# Change Airport signal strength

Tags: macos, airport

I want to change the WiFi signal strength of my Airport base. That feature was removed along many others in the Airport configuration tool since version 6, so I used the previous version to solve my problem like this:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3974623?tstart=0

However the latest version before 6.0 (seems to be 5.6.1) cannot be installed in Mavericks.

How can I access to the lost AirPort configuration features now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make 5.6.1 work with on Mavericks with a workaround, as detailed here:

http://coreyjmahler.com/2013/10/24/airport-utility-5-6-1-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks/

> The issue with AirPort Utility v5.6.1 under OS X 10.9 Mavericks is
>   that a system file upon which AirPort Utility relies was updated in
>   10.9 and that update broke backwards compatibility with AirPort Utility v5.6.1. The file in question is Apple80211 in
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A.
>   Replacing this file with the older version allows AirPort Utility
>   v5.6.1 to be run under 10.9, but only via Terminal (i.e.,
>   double-clicking it will not launch it, it will throw an error).
>
> However, there is a way to get around this issue by importing the older library into AirPort Utility v5.6.1 before running it. That is
>   what the new solution, downloadable, infra, does.

Answer (score 3):

You could install Mountain Lion in a VM (both VMWare and Parallels will do) and run APU 5.6.1 from there. I'm using this to still be able to switch between Aiport Profiles (which also are gone in APU 6.x).

Comment: If access to Windows is an option then http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1547 can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Apple still has the link:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1536

Using third-party vendors for downloading this I would not recommend.